# Swift: (Pre-)load UIWebView from initialViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, instantiation, nsurlrequest

I have two ViewControllers. The initial ViewController is where the URL is entered and stored. The viewDidLoad of this initial ViewController is also supposed to start loading the web content for the second ViewController on start of the app.

The secondViewController consists only of a WebView.

When I start the app, func loadWebView in the secondViewController is successfully called. However, once I click the goButton to present the secondViewController. It comes up empty. (Calling func loadWebView locally in the secondViewController viewDidLoad will successfully load the website.)

I think I did something wrong the way I instantiate the secondViewController and the way I call it. I think somehow I am creating two different instances of secondViewController and call the empty one. I'd be happy about any pointers.

EDIT: I want the app to start loading the website as soon as the initial ViewController is opened. Not only when I access the secondViewController.

EDIT2: Could the issue be that the data of the initial call of webView.loadRequest(request) does not get saved to the webView-subview? Calling the webView the second time it comes up blank because no data has been saved. Does anyone know how to save/load data from a loadRequest call?

EDIT3: Forget about EDIT2. Read the comments underneath the correct answer for the solution!

initial ViewController:

```
var svc: UIViewController = UIViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    loadWebView("https://www.google.com")
}

func loadWebView(URLString:String) {

    if let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: URLString) {
    let theRequest = NSURLRequest (URL: theRequestURL) 

    let vc: secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! secondViewController

        vc.loadWebView(theRequest)
        svc = vc
    } 
}

@IBAction func goButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.presentViewController(svc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

secondViewController:

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView! = UIWebView()

func loadWebView(request : NSURLRequest) {
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about two instances of `secondViewController`, but probably two of `webView`...assuming you defined one in your storyboard.  Instantiating the `IBOutlet` is unusual/wrong.

I suggest turning `loadWebView` into something like `storeRequestURL`.  Save the request to an instance variable and then call `loadRequest` in `viewWillAppear` (or maybe `viewDidLoad`) of `secondViewController`.

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that with your suggestion the loadRequest will only start when the secondViewController is called? I want the website to be loaded as soon as the initialViewController is opened. Basically having preloaded the site, so it instantly comes up when I go to the secondViewController.

Comment: In that case, you might try not making the web view an outlet and (therefore) not defining/connecting it in the storyboard.  Instead, you would create it in code -- as you do now -- and then add it as a subview to the controller's view after the view loads.  (Your code is then responsible for size and positioning.)

Comment: I deleted the WebView from the storyboard and it's outlet from secondViewController. Creating `var webView: UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 420, 725))` and calling in viewWillAppear `self.view.addSubview(webView)`. However, same situation as before. WebView comes up blank when called from the initial ViewController. Running the loadWebView in the viewDidLoad of secondViewController it displays the site.

Comment: Do you think the issue might be that the data of the initial call of `webView.loadRequest(request)` does not get saved to the `webView` subview? Calling the `webView` the second time it comes up blank because no data has been saved. Do you know how to save data from the `loadRequest` call?

Comment: Something else is happening that we haven't looked at.  I just created a new project and set it up with code to match your comment starting "I deleted the WebView..." and it works fine for me.  I get the Google page when I tap the button.  Is your button really connected to the action?  If you use Xcode's View Debugging, do you see your web view on the screen?

Comment: The `goButton` shows a Sent Events - Touch Up Inside -> initialViewController goButton in the Connections Inspector. It will then call `self.presentViewController(svc, animated: false, completion: nil)`, which takes it to the secondViewController instantiated in the `loadWebView` of the initialViewController: `let vc: secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondViewController") as! secondViewController`. Would you mind sharing your project file with me?

Comment: @Peanutsmasher I'm not sure how well dropbox will work for this, but try: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b49bf3z43wsec1j/WebViewTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Unfortunately all I am getting is an 404 error. However, I rewrote the project from scratch and voila, you're right. It works! Feels like I copy & pasted everything. Must've missed something in the old file. One more question, where do I put the `self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true`, it seems no matter where I put it, the webView ignores it. Thank you so much for your help! People like you and this site make beginner's life so much easier!

Comment: I haven't used that.  I can see that the view behaves a little bit differently for true and false but I don't know how the zooming is supposed to work.